# In MongoDB Shell, How to query for day-by-day data for a time period (such as a month)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I want to get day wise data grouped by class (field from my collection) for a month of period.

This is what i have tried to query, but doesn't give the expected output.

**query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Get only records created in the last 30 days
    {$match:{
          "created_at":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*30)},       
    }},

    // Get the year, month and day from the created_at TimeStamp
    {$project:{
          "year":{$year:"$created_at"}, 
          "month":{$month:"$created_at"}, 
          "day": {$dayOfMonth:"$created_at"}
    }}, 

    // Group by year, month and day and get the count
    {$group:{
          _id:{year:"$year", month:"$month", day:"$day"}, 
          "count":{$sum:1}
    }},

    // Group by class field
    { $group: {
          _id: "$meta.class", 
          total: {$sum: 1}
    }}  
])
```

**expected output:**

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2021, "month" : 10, "day" : 01 }, "count" : {{ "_id" : "class1", "total" : 15 }, { "_id" : "class2", "total" : 25 }} }
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2021, "month" : 10, "day" : 02 }, "count" : {{ "_id" : "class2", "total" : 25 }, { "_id" : "class3", "total" : 10 }} }
...
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2021, "month" : 10, "day" : 30 }, "count" : {{ "_id" : "class3", "total" : 50 }} }
```

So, could someone please tell me how to attain the desired result or what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

---EDIT---

Sample Data:

> mongoplayground link : [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dPCamZC3feL)

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "_id": ObjectId("615602280000000000000000"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2021-09-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "meta": {
      "class": "class1",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "_id": ObjectId("615753a80000000000000000"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2021-10-01T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "meta": {
      "class": "class1",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "_id": ObjectId("615764100000000000000000"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2021-10-01T19:40:00.000Z"),
    "meta": {
      "class": "class1",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    "_id": ObjectId("615776d00000000000000000"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2021-10-01T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "meta": {
      "class": "class2",
      
    }
  }
]
```

sample o/p:

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "year":2021,
         "month":10,
         "day":1
      },
      "count":[
         {
            "_id":"class1",
            "total":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "year":2021,
         "month":10,
         "day":2
      },
      "count":[
         {
            "_id":"class1",
            "total":2
         },
         {
            "_id":"class2",
            "total":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: 1. try replacing `$project` stage with `$addFields`. You are currently dropping all information except the derived year and month and day. 2. you cannot stack two `$group` together like in the way like your current attempt. That will make second `$group` lacking the required info for grouping

Comment: You can share a sample dataset for us to try to replicate your situation and see what we can help

Comment: @ray added sample dataset, for better understanding

Comment: The sample o/p is invalid JSON, please provide valid samples.

Comment: sorry mb, fixed it

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the help, this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { created_at: { $gt: moment().startOf('day').subtract(30, 'day').toDate() } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            day: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$created_at", unit: "day" } },
            class: "$meta.class"
         },
         total: { $count: {} }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$_id.day",
         count: { $push: { total: "$total", class: "$_id.class" } }
      }
   }
])
```

Whenever I have to work with date/time values then I suggest to use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library.

`$dateTrunc()` requires MongoDB version 5.0. If you prefer or require year/month/day parts it should be fairly obvious how to modify the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: added sample dataset, for better understanding. pls have a look.